# Can you collect california short term disability if you only have to stop working one of two jobs?

Tags: united-states, disability, california

Background:
1 Full time in office job
1 Part time job, working remote from home

Situation:
Surgery with 4 week recovery time.  Will not be able to work full time job because it is a physical job. They are able to keep working the remote computer based job.

Question: Does California Short Term Disability Insurance allow for one to collect for just the full time job while they are still working a part time 2nd job?

Comment: Might want to ask this in the Law StackExchange.

Comment: If you can work, do you deserve a disability payment or should you let someone more deserving have it?

Comment: @SolarMike 1) Well, the said person can work remotely for a computer based job and its only part time. The full time job is physical work and can not be done after surgery. 2)  Presumably they've been paying into the disability system, so not sure why they wouldn't be entitled to it when they're recovering from surgery. Would you only use your home insurance if you couldn't afford it? or if you had the money would you pay for your burnt up house so someone else more deserving can use the insurance money? despite the fact you've been paying for your home insurance for years?

Comment: The person will need to [report both jobs](https://www.edd.ca.gov/unemployment/fraud_and_penalties_what_you_need_to_know.htm) and the wages from both when they file and keep reporting the wages from the part-time job. How that will affect the benefit amount I don't know.

Comment: For clarity, this is for short term disability and not unemployment(the link is for unemployment insurance it looks like). They have no problem reporting both jobs, I'm just having trouble figuring out the rules and if there's a point to file for it at all, or if they'll be rejected since they still have income or not, and trying to figure our what kind of income they need to plan for.

Comment: Does either company have a short term disability benefit? All my employers have had that type of program. I have used it twice. Note that they weren't California employers.

Comment: Are you certain this is the correct program? I'm not in CA (but still in the US), and have dealt with a lot of applications for disability benefits and they don't generally work this way in my experience. *Social Security Disability Insurance* (SSDI) has far less "short term" character than people often think, and the far more common short-term disability insurance available is an explicit insurance plan offered by an employer. If I'm mistaken on the CA program, could you link to an official site describing the relevant government-managed insurance program?

Comment: @Upper_Case here's the program, it's specifically for short term, and California requires a payroll tax to be withheld from paychecks to fund it https://www.edd.ca.gov/Disability/

Comment: Thank you! That resolves all questions I had, and my observations do not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 5):

As per [EDD for california](https://www.edd.ca.gov/disability/Am_I_Eligible_for_DI_Benefits.htm):

> In order to be eligible for DI benefits, you must:
>
> Be unable to do your regular or customary work for at least eight
>   days.
>
> Be employed or actively looking for work at the time your
>   disability begins.
>
> Have lost wages because of your disability.
>
> [..]

As you are unable to do your regular hours and are actually wages, it seems that under those circumstances, you may be eligible for something, maybe even the ordinary amount, if otherwise, you would keep both jobs and not use the part-time as a replacement.

Comment: Could you add a link for this information?

Comment: @Upper_Case done.

Answer (score 2):

> For all part-time, intermittent, reduced hours, and reduced wage situations, the Employment Development Department (EDD) suggests that you file a claim, and after we receive your properly completed claim, we will determine if you are eligible for Disability Insurance (DI) or Paid Family Leave (PFL) benefits.
> ...
> If you return to work on a part-time basis because you are unable to perform your regular or customary work, and have a continued wage loss due to your disability or family care, you may be eligible to receive continued DI or PFL benefits.

https://www.edd.ca.gov/disability/Part-time_Intermittent_Reduced_Work_Schedule.htmThis is arguably not the exact situation you describe, but the general principle seems to be that you can collect benefits even if you're still working, if you're getting less money.

In a comment, you say:

> I'm just having trouble figuring out the rules and if there's a point to file for it at all, or if they'll be rejected since they still have income or not, and trying to figure our what kind of income they need to plan for.

For the question "Will the application be accepted", I would say "Probably", but for "Should I submit an application and see what happens", I'd say "Sure".

Answer (score 1):

It depends. To be eligible for disability you have to meet certain conditions including being unable to perform your job duties. Depending on what type of job duties you have, it could be a situation where due to the surgery, you might be able to perform one job and not the other, but I would expect that such a case would need to be readily apparent or easy for them to verify.

Comment: So as long as they are not able to work the full time, and able to work the part time, they should be able to collect? The part time is remote, in home, computer work. The full time is a physical job. I assume it would be easy to have a doctor write up a letter for it.

Comment: Would that require being honest about all one’s job duties?

Comment: @SolarMike Are you for some reason suggesting someone is not being honest here, Mike?

Comment: @Kyle will you declare both jobs? Will you declare all the duties? Given your question... let me guess...

Comment: This isn't even about me personally, but if this person just wanted to work the system they wouldn't work either job and collect disability, easy peasy. But, they want to keep working what they can. One can be done from a tablet at home, the other one requires heavy lifting all day and they are getting major back surgery. Are you just on SO to be hostile to people?

Comment: @Kyle my comments made you provide more information and clarification to your question, which would have been easier if you had made it clear at first post....